# The method in the protocol extension is never get called, plus, an error in the book

Tags: swift, protocols

At page 261 ~ 262 of the book "*Swift ApprenticeBeginning programming with Swift 2.2*" there is a sample code about protocol extension is shown as follow

the value `gamesPlayed` is defined in the protocol `TeamRecord`, the protocol extension and the structure `BaseballRecord`

```
    protocol TeamRecord {
        var wins: Int { get }
        var losses: Int { get }
        var gamesPlayed: Int { get }
    }

    extension TeamRecord {
        // gamesPlay#1
        var gamesPlayed: Int {
            return (wins + losses)
        }
    }

    struct BaseballRecord: TeamRecord{
        var wins: Int
        var losses: Int
        // gamesPlay#2
        let gamesPlayed: Int = 162
    }

    let team1: TeamRecord = BaseballRecord(wins: 10, losses: 5)
    let team2: BaseballRecord = BaseballRecord(wins: 10, losses: 5)

    team1.gamesPlayed//The book claimed it will invoke "gamesPlay#1" (15)
    team2.gamesPlayed//The book claimed it will invoke "gamesPlay#2" (162)
```

Problem: According to the description of the book, the `gamesPlayed` called by **team1** invokes the implementation in the protocol extension (`gamesPlay#1`); while the `gamesPlayed` called by **team2** invokes the implementation (`gamesPlay#2`) in the `BaseballRecord` structure.

But the Xcode 7.3 playground told me a different story, both `team1.gamesPlayed` and `team2.gamesPlayed` invokes the implementation in the structure rather than the protocol extension.

[image]

**Question** I might be misled by the sloppy writing of this part of the book! If not, please correct me. (the picture here is captured from the book)

Thanks a lot for your kind help and time

**Extra Staff:** Dear friends. In case you found this question and also bothered by the same issue, here comes the simple self-contained code I wrote after I learned from the kind helpers. Just copy and paste it into your Xcode playground. Hope this will help you a bit.

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    func hardCasting()
}

extension MyProtocol {
    func foo() {
    print("Printing from the protocol extension")
    }

    func fooDefaul() {
    print("Not implemented in type, I'm  prented from the protocol extension")
    }

    func hardCasting() {
    print("You shouldn't see this!!! YOU SHALL NOT PASS!")
    }
}

struct MyType: MyProtocol {
    func foo() {
    print("Printing from the type")
    }

    func hardCasting() {
    print("No matter what! I get only printed out by type!")
    }
}

let lumi: MyProtocol = MyType()

lumi.foo()
lumi.fooDefaul()

let lumiProtocol: MyProtocol = MyType()
let lumiType: MyType = MyType()

lumiProtocol.hardCasting()
lumiType.hardCasting()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, this is an error in the book. Concrete implementations are always selected before a protocol extension *if* the method is declared in the protocol definition itself.

However, if the method is added by protocol extension, is *not* declared in the protocol definition, and is also implemented in a concrete type, you *can* get the extension's implementation by casting the concrete type to the protocol.

In other words, if the sample code had included this:

```
protocol TeamRecord {
    var wins: Int { get }
    var losses: Int { get }
}
```

instead of this:

```
protocol TeamRecord {
    var wins: Int { get }
    var losses: Int { get }
    var gamesPlayed: Int { get }
}
```

then the comments in the book would be correct.

There's a very thorough exploration of this here:

https://nomothetis.svbtle.com/the-ghost-of-swift-bugs-future

Comment: @Danien Hall Thanks a lot for your help and the reading resource, I was confused a lot by that part of the chapter.

Comment: @SLN  That's understandable!  Pretty much everyone I know has been confused by that until dealing with it enough times to start remembering how it works  :)

Comment: Big thanks again!, I'm reading the page you shared here, very nice staff! Happy to have you here. I'll try to write more testing code to further learning